# Csv upload to mysql in perl

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, csv

I am new in perl programming language. Can you please guide how to write csv upload into mysql database.

I have following table & csv file format

**Create Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE consumeruser (
  ConsumerId    int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ConsumerName  varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  ConsumerMobNo varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ConsumerId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4494 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Csv file example:**

```
4495,Sanchita Mehra,999999999
4496,Rupesh Shewalkar,88888888
4497,Aditya Mishra,111111111
```

Csv upload should be on basis of mobile number, suppose if table already contain mobile 111111111 Then that row should be skip. Means all mobile numbers should be check with existing data, if it is already in database that row should not be insert in database & rest of inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the count of the row to see if the data is already present and then continue to next statement if its present. The implementation is for SQLite and you can change it to MySQL.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl '2012';
use DBD::SQLite;
use warnings;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=Consumer");

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my ($id, $name, $MobNo) = split /,/;
    my $query = "select count(*) from consumeruser where ConsumerMobNo = ?";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($MobNo);
    my $row = $sth->fetch();
    next if(@$row > 0);
    my $insertStatement = "insert into consumeruser values(?,'?',?)";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($insertStatement);
    $sth->execute($id,$name,$MobNo);
}

__DATA__
4495,Sanchita Mehra,999999999
4496,Rupesh Shewalkar,88888888
4497,Aditya Mishra,111111111
4498,Aditya,111111111
```

Edit:

For fetching all the mobile numbers in the array. You can do like this.

```
my @MobileNumbers;
my $mobileNumberQuery = "select ConsumerMobNo from consumeruser";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($mobileNumberQuery);
$sth->execute();
while(my $row = $sth->fetch()){
   push @MobileNumbers, @$row;
}
```

Please refer to `perldoc DBI` for various ways of accessing the results.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, how do I do with array or hash so that I not need select each mobile number each time.

Comment: For every Record insert I need to check whether current mobile number exists or not in database. How should I write code so that one query get all mobile numbers & stores into array or Hash, insert will be on basis of array or hash value. if it present in array or hash then skip that row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please refer to perldoc DBI for various ways of accessing the results. @user3639608